# Save a named sheet as a CSV file in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some sheets open in my Excel workbook and I need to save only one of them (`sinani-05`) with a specific name in CSV format. Can you please let me know how to do this?

I already found this on StackOverflow:

```
WS.SaveAs "E:\\Data\CSV\" & WS.Name & ".csv", xlCSV
```

but I'm not sure how to update it to save only the mentioned sheet (`sinani-05`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Copy()` function to copy a worksheet to a new workbook, then save the new workbook. For example:

```
' This copies the sheet named "sinani-05" to a new workbook...
Sheets("sinani-05").Copy

' and this saves the new workbook as a CSV...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "E:\Data\CSV\sinani-05.csv", xlCSV
```

Comment: great thanks again Bond this is working, however I am not sure why I am not able to open the `sinani-05.csv` with Bracket code editor! it is available with Notepad++. .do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It should work. I opened a CSV in Brackets on my PC without any problems. You could try asking this question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour), though. It may be a better fit there.